# Multiselect not displaying correctly inside instance-settings-modal - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, multi-select

I've created a custom shipping method for Woocommerce which supports `shipping-zones`, `instance-settings` and `instance-settings-modal`. The form fields for instance-settings are created using [Settings API](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Settings-API) of Woocommerce as below:

```
$settings = array(
    'title' => array(
        'title'         => __( 'Method title', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'          => 'text',
        'description'   => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'default'       => __( 'Flat rate', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
    ),
    'tax_status' => array(
        'title'         => __( 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => 'wc-enhanced-select',
        'default'       => 'taxable',
        'options'       => array(
            'taxable'   => __( 'Taxable', 'woocommerce' ),
            'none'      => _x( 'None', 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
        ),
    ),
    'cities' => array(
        'title'         => __( 'Cities', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'          => 'multiselect',
        'description'   => __( 'Select all cities within current zone to which this shipping method applies.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'class'         => 'wc-enhanced-select',
        'options'       => $zone_cities,
    ),
    'cost' => array(
        'title'         => __( 'Cost', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'          => 'text',
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'description'   => $cost_desc,
        'default'       => '0',
        'desc_tip'      => true,
    ),
);
```

Everything is working fine except the multiselect field for `cities` not working properly. It is being displayed as a normal select with multiple attribute. Here's a screenshot:

[image: wc-settings-modal]

While, when I use only `instance-settings` the multiselect also works fine. Here's another screenshot:

[image]

The same issue is closed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12352). Any help to find the underlying problem is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** The problem can be reproduced in Flat rate shipping method of Woocommerce core, if you change the `tax_status` field type to `multiselect` from `select`.

Change line #22 of `woocommerce/includes/shipping/flat-rate/includes/settings-flat-rate.php` as below:

```
$settings = array(
    'title' => array(
        'title'         => __( 'Method title', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'          => 'text',
        'description'   => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'default'       => __( 'Flat rate', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
    ),
    'tax_status' => array(
        'title'         => __( 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'          => 'multiselect', // *** Change here ***
        'class'         => 'wc-enhanced-select',
        'default'       => 'taxable',
        'options'       => array(
            'taxable'   => __( 'Taxable', 'woocommerce' ),
            'none'      => _x( 'None', 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
        ),
    ),
    'cost' => array(
        'title'         => __( 'Cost', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'          => 'text',
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'description'   => $cost_desc,
        'default'       => '0',
        'desc_tip'      => true,
    ),
);
```

Comment: Could you please add the minimal complete code in your question as *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**"*.

Comment: Maybe you are facing a javaScript error. Have you checked the console?

Comment: @ParantapParashar There are no errors in console.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I've provided `$settings` array which was passed to `WC_Shipping_Method::instance_form_fields` property in order to create the settings form. I've followed the Woocommerce Shipping API and Settings API to create this custom shipping method. The problem is same as mentioned in this Github [issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12352).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec You can ask for the required code, otherwise I've to upload all plugin files. There's nothing so strange going in other plugin files.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Look for updated question to reproduce the problem.